# Select where column value begins with one of multiple values in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to select all rows where a certain VARCHAR column begins with one of multiple choices.
I have tried the following solutions:

```
{
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      {
        col_name: {
          [Op.startsWith]: 'a'
        },
      },
      {
        col_name: {
          [Op.startsWith]: 'b'
        },
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

This one nearly works, only that for some reason the [Op.or] translate into AND in the raw query.

I have also tried

```
{
  where: {
    col_name: {
      [Op.startsWith]: ['a', 'b']
    }
  }
}
```

which translates the array into a single string 'a,b'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it eventually, here's the solution:

```
where: {
  col_name: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { [Op.startsWith]: 'a' },
      { [Op.startsWith]: 'b' },
    ]
  }
}
```